# CString to double with _stscanf_s_l

Tags: c++, mfc, type-conversion, variant

I am in a c ++ (2010), MFC, `COleVariant` context.

I am facing a problem converting between a `CString` and a double using `_stscanf_s_l`.

Indeed some string is found converted with a large number of decimal places without my understanding why.

I present an example to illustrate the case:

```
CString szChaine(newValue.bstrVal); 
// --> szChaine =
// --> Example 1 : "102.09"
// --> Example 2 : "102.10" 
// --> Example 3 : "102.11" 
// --> Example 4 : "14.44"
// --> Example 5 : "14.45"
// --> Example 6 : "14.46"


double dbl;

_locale_t loc = _create_locale(LC_ALL, "C");
int nRet = _stscanf_s_l(szChaine,_T("%lf"), loc ,&dbl);
_free_locale(loc);

//--> dbl = 
// --> Example 1 : 102.09
// --> Example 2 : 102.09999999999999
// --> Example 3 : 102.11 
// --> Example 4 : 14.44
// --> Example 5 : 14.449999999999999
// --> Example 6 : 14.46
```

With or without a locale the problem remains the same.

`newValue` is a `COleVariant` of type `VT_BSTR`.
My goal is to get a `double`.
I tried the `ChangeType` method on the `COleVariant` like this
`newValue.ChangeType(VT_R8);`

but `ChangeType` throws an exception, hence my attempt with `_stscanf_s_l`.

Do you have an explanation or a solution?

Comment: Not sure how are you printing those values, but probably during printing you may need to set the precision till which you want to print a double value.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @bar You **cannot** round to a floating point number that doesn't exist. Not every decimal can be represented in a finite floating point number (such as `0.1`). No amount of rounding will make that fundamental truth go away.

Comment: @IInspectable I mean it can be expected if `"0.1"` turned in to `0.09999999` in decimal->binary->decimal conversion. You can round that by looking at the text input. I think OP has a typo where `"102.09"` turns in to `~102.10`, that's off by a factor of `0.0001`  using `double` precision. You are right in general, for example a larger number `"1000000.092"` may turn in to `"1000000.02784"`, rounding to arbitrary precision is not possible.

Comment: @bar Example 2 is perfectly expected. The string literal `"102.10"` gets turned into a floating point value of approx. `102.09999999999999` (represented in decimal). The vital point is: Converting decimal into binary floating point is a **lossy** operation. If you don't want to lose information, don't convert. Alternatively, you need to persist the lost information. Note that converting binary floating point into decimal is lossless.

Comment: @IInspectable, the real problem is I can't read right, I read the question the wrong way. My comment are totally irrelevant.

Comment: One note, floating point numbers should not be used for representing "amount"-type data, because they may not be able to represent all values exactly. Especially comparisons (and I'm talking mostly about equality comparisons) may fail because of this. In these cases you should rather use some fixed-point arithmetic (you need to write a small library for conversions or other processing). A common choice is the 64-bit integer, representing the amount in cents. It can't represent smaller amounts (this is generally OK though) but has enough range for almost everything and the required precision

Comment: In my vba projects I rounded my variables to x decimal places are then compared them. Up until now it worked sufficiently. But I agree with everything that has been said.